# V and W and Z are Poisson distributions

Tags: poisson-distribution, covariance

V∼P(λ) and W∼P(λ) and Z∼P(λ) meaning that V and W and Z are Poisson distributions and independent.
X=W+V and Y=V+Z
qus1: what cov(X,Y)?
qus2: Do X,Y are independent?
qus3: F(X,Y)=?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why don't you use the bilinearity property of covariance $cov(V+W,V+Z)=cov(V,V)+cov(V,Z)+cov(W,V)+cov(W,Z)=cov(V,V)=...$ ?